# Is there any way of proving law of conservation of momentum theoretically rather experimentally or mathematically?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws

I understand it requires Newton's third law but how to prove it. Is it like an axiom in physics like in mathematics. in mathematics you cannot prove it, in physics you cannot explain it elementarly (if that's a word).

Comment: Do you already know about [Noether's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether's_theorem)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.